# Place a button in JFace tableviewer column

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

I'm working on Eclipse RCP Viewer framework, i have a requirement to place a button widget in column of `TableViewer`.
I have been following the  [tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) to develop my application

I don't find any widget inside the tableviewer, as in the example it was just an image, is it possible to place a widget, any idea please suggest me.

I've searched API to find any predefined method like `getWidget()` similar to `getImage()` ,that can be placed in `col.setLabelProvider()`, but there was none actually,How can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to use editing support or for instance DialogCellEditor

> http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FDialogCellEditor.html